# Debug webservice from android app in the same network

Tags: android, web-services, vpn

I'm developing an app for android that consumes a .NET webservice. This part is ok, I've already tested in the vm and my app does call the webservice and do what its supposed to do.
The problem is that i need to test it "live" now. As my app needs bluetooth and other stuff that the emulator can't provide I have to deploy it in my phone and try out.

The real problem is that my webservice is hosted in my computer (not in IIS). How can i connect to the webservice?
I've already set a VPN connection in my computer so that i could be in the same network. The connection was ok and i could ping my computer from my android phone (i downloaded an app for that). But i tried to call the webservice using my computer's ip and it doesn't work. 
I use this address on browser: http://192.168.56.1:49365/DataUpload.asmx (where 192.168.56.1 is the ip from my computer and DataUpload.asmx is the name of the webservice)

The name of the webservice is ok and the ip too but i can't see the webservice.

Does anyone knows how to help me? I suppose is something with the port or something like that (MY FIREWALL IS DISABLED).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly 192.168.56.1 is your router, this is pretty much the norm.  To be sure, go to your computer and use the same address in your browser there as you tried on the phone.

Post your results.

One other thing, you'll have to turn off the 'Cellular' radio in your phone to be sure it only connects via WiFi.  Otherwise you'll have to find out what IP address you have at your house and point your phone at that IP and port forward from your router to your local machine.